# Yii2-how to save data items for multiple selected numbers using typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, typeahead.js

I am working on `yii2`. I have a controller in which I am using `typeahead` to select multiple `reference numbers`.

```
     var surveyReferences = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('ref_no'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      prefetch: 'survey',
      remote: {
        url: 'survey/?q=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
      }
    });

    $('#the-ref-id').typeahead(null, {
      limit: 50,
      name: 'ref-numbers',
      display: 'ref_no',
      source: surveyReferences,
      suggestion: function(data) {
return '<p><strong>' + data.ref_no + '</strong> – ' + data.ref_no + '</p>';
    }
    });

});


jQuery('#the-ref-id').on('typeahead:selected',function(e,datum) {
         console.log(datum);
          var html = '<div class="selected-refs"><input type="hidden" name="selected_refs[]" value="'+datum.ref_no+'" />'+datum.ref_no+'<a onclick="$(this).closest(\'.selected-refs\').remove()">X</a></div>';
           $('#selected_ref_container').append(html); 
           $('#the-ref-id').typeahead('val','');

      });
```

Now when I select a reference number there are some other fields which I also want to save. My console log is below

```
{id: "303", ref_no: "28371510884400U", consumer_name: "MUNICIPAL CORPORATION HALI ROAD HYD", consumer_address: "MUNICIPAL CORPORATION HALI ROAD HYD", sync_date: "2017-05-04 03:54:32", …}
```

I want to save the above data while selecting reference numbers. Below is my create controller

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['selected_refs']))
    {

        foreach($_REQUEST['selected_refs'] as $k=>$v)
        {

            $m = new RouteRefs;
            $m ->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $m->ref_no = $v;
            $m->created_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $m->created_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

            if ($m->save())
            {
                //do not return from here
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->render('create',[
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $m->id]);
    }else
    {
        return $this->render('create',[
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

One way is to make a function and pass `ref_no` in it and then save all the values one by one.

But this is a very long method, is there any other way to save all the data?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by long method?

Comment: and can you add you complete action code you line `return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $m->id]);` is strange why you submit $model id to index page , it would have only the last inserted id of the model whereas you have mutiple `selected_refs`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the above-written code is my whole action code

Comment: ok, what is in the `$_REQUEST['selected_refs']`, and the data you have to save will go into which model?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam it includes the selected `reference number` and the data would be saved in `RouteRef` model

Comment: one more question do you want to save the data as soon as you select any option from the typeahead? means inside the `typeahead:selected'` event ?